# ng-repeat elements are not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my application I'm making a get request through Angular's http service and in the view looping over the returned data to show an unordered list. But the problem is even though data is available after the get request , its not getting dispplyed on the page. Seems to be a CSS style problem, but don't know how to fix it. I want to show the unorder list within a bootstrap panel as a body.

Below is the angular piece of code inside the controlller for setting up the data

```
$http.get('/messages').success(function(data) {
         console.log("Messages are "+data);
         $scope.records=data;
     });
```

Here is the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery Bootstrap News plugin</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/css/custom.css"/>  
    <script src="/libs/js/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/libs/js/newsbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/libs/js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/libs/js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="mean" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <br/>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span><b> What you wanna do before you die ...</b>
            </div>
            <div ng-cloak class="panel-body">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">                 
                    <ul class="demo1">                    
                        <li class="news-item" ng-repeat="item in records">                    
                         <table cellpadding="4">                         
                            <tr>
                            <td >
                             <img  class="img-circle" width="60" 
                                  ng-src="/images/{{($index+11) % 10}}.png"/>
                            </td>
                            <td ng-cloak>
                                {{$index+1}}. {{item.username}} 
                            </td>
                            </tr>                             
                         </table>                        
                        </li>                     
                    </ul>                    
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>            
            <div class="panel-footer"></div>              
           </div>
        </div>          
    </div>

        <div class="row">
  <div  class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 ">
    <form  name="messageForm" novalidate="novalidate" ng-submit="onSubmit()" id="message-box">
      <div class="form-group">
       <textarea required  ng-model="formModel.message" 
                 style="background-color:#ffffe6;border:double 4px orange;border-radius: 0.5em;"                        rows="3" cols="50" id="message" placeholder="Write your message and press enter..">          </textarea>      

          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Shoot it</button>
        </div>  
        <p ng-cloak class="help-block" ng-show="formModel.nameError">Looks like you forgot to mention your name !!!</p>
        <p ng-cloak class="help-block" ng-show="formModel.messageEmpty">Really you don't wanna do anything before you die !!! </p>
        <p ng-cloak class="help-block" ng-show="formModel.messageTooLong">You are trying to do too many things buddy, just 150 characters !!! </p>
   </form>
 </div>            
        </div>  


</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(".demo1").bootstrapNews({
            newsPerPage: 12,
            autoplay: true,
            pauseOnHover:true,
            direction: 'up',
            newsTickerInterval: 4000,
            onToDo: function () {
                //console.log(this);
            }
        });

    });
</script>


</body>

</html>
```

When I check through chrome dev tool, data is present in that unordered list, data is present but somehow not getting displayed properly within bootstrap panel.

See this image

[image: undefined tag]

I noticed there is one undefined element at the bottom of unordered list while checking through dev tools. Any idea whats going wrong?

The panel body is empty
[image: undefined tag]

Comment: In the array. is there any undefined elements?

Comment: The problem could be because both Angular and jQuery are trying to manipulate the same DOM elements.

Comment: hi @Ashan there is no undefined element in the data returned

Comment: @Lex I'm using a jQuery plugin which requires jquery to be loaded, So I have to use jQuery along with Angular

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Why is the [ul] tag style set to "height:0px; overflow-y:hidden"?   -- this would hide your content

you could also move the ng-cloak to the div.panel-body to the div.row and remove it from the child td

--

Delay bootstrapNews binding

```
$(function(){
   if ($('.panel-body[ng-cloak]').length > 0)
       return window.setTimeout(arguments.callee, 10);

   $(".demo1").bootstrapNews({...});
});
```

Comment: I have removed the css height:0px; overflow-y:hidden which was applied by one of the library https://github.com/gagi270683/jQuery-bootstrap that I was using, one problem though there is a undefined tag after last li. Where this come from, I don't have this in my markup. And also now the actual jquery plugin I am using to scroll down the news is not working, possibly because of this undefined tag. Please see the updated question

Comment: It may come for the "bootstrapNews" --- disable this to verify and perhaps delay it until after the angular bindings

Comment: Yes @Steve that undefined was because of bootstrapNews, when I disabled it , undefined disapear. How can I delay it so that it works after Angular has finished

Comment: Either delay it a few seconds to see if the delay would help.  If it does work, the ng-cloak attribute gets removed on render so you could poll for that - added to the bottom of my answer

Comment: I added a delay to the javascript for jquery plugin and it works, but thats not a full proof solution. <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       
       setTimeout(function(){
            $(".demo1").bootstrapNews({
            newsPerPage: 5, 
            autoplay: true,
   pauseOnHover:true,
            direction: 'up',
            newsTickerInterval: 2000,
            onToDo: function () {
                console.log(this);
            }
        });
       },4000);
  
    });
</script> How should I make sure javascript only runs when data is fetched

Comment: The delay method I added to the bottom of my answer should minimize the the delay to just after its painted --- vs the 4 seconds in your poc

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write a directive for getting a callback when ng-repeat is done and that is a better solution instead of any 'delay' tactics.

Might help you to go through how I have done in my code- used a directive to emit a render finished event:

```
dashboard.directive('onFinishRender', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit(attr.onFinishRender);
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In the controller I keep the event listener:

```
    $scope.$on('dataLoaded', function(ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
        // your code to add bootstrapNews binding
    });
```

and in the html side, I call them like this:

```
<div class="add_tenant_name" ng-repeat="tenant in tenants" on-finish-render="dataLoaded">
    // more divs
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @kukkuz I did that, I will post my answer, thanks for taking time in writing your point. I achieved that using a directive.